# Is it possible to get a file without knowing its extension?

Tags: go, filesystems

I need to get a file with a known path and name, even though I don't know exactly its extension

for example:

```
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test.txt")
```

works.

but

```
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test")
```

don't

Comment: The extension is part of the file name. `test.txt` and `test` are two different names.

Comment: An alternative is to get all file name in the directory and find the target file with `strings.HasPrefix`.

Comment: If the directory `./` contains `./test.txt` and `./test.jpeg` which file would you like `ioutil.ReadFile` to open @ERVIN228? You have to specify a valid filepath, which must include the file's filename extension, if it has one. If you want something more lax then you have to implement that yourself, e.g. you can loop over the directory's file entries and read the first file whose name is as close a match as you would like.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this code was for a general purpose library where there might be other prefix-based functionality, I might model it like this:

```
package prefixpath

var (
    ErrNoMatch  = errors.New("prefixpath: no matches")
    ErrMultiple = errors.New("prefixpath: more than one match")
)

func ReadFirst(prefix string) ([]byte, error) {
    paths, err := filepath.Glob(prefix + ".*")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(paths) == 0 {
        return nil, ErrNoMatch
    }
    if len(paths) > 1 {
        return nil, ErrMultiple
    }
    return ioutil.ReadFile(paths[0])
}
```

Then for your original code:

```
data, err := prefixpath.ReadFirst("./test") // import of package prefixpath omitted
```

Comment: You probably didn't want to name your function `FirstFirst` but `ReadFirst`, am I right? ;)